# css style for multiple html id tags

Tags: css

I have several similar html ids, example:

```
<il id="DashboardPoolAvailable_1"></il>
<il id="DashboardPoolAvailable_2"></il>
<il id="DashboardPoolAvailable_3"></il>
<il id="DashboardPoolAvailable_4"></il>
....
```

I need to build a unique CSS code that will work for all the DashboardPoolAvailable_* ids. Something like:

`#DashboardPoolAvailable_* { display: inline-block; width: 924px; margin: 0px 13px;` }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[id^="DashboardPoolAvailable_"]
{
    //styles
}
```

A better way would be to put all the `li`'s into a UL with a class, and then use something like:

```
.ul-class li
{
    //styles
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If a style is used for more than one element it should really be a class not an id.

consider re-factoring to this:

```
<div class="DashboardPoolAvailable" id="dash1"></div>
<div class="DashboardPoolAvailable" id="dash2"></div>
<div class="DashboardPoolAvailable" id="dash3"></div>


.DashboardPoolAvailable {
  //all shared properties
}

#dash1{ //unique styles}
#dash2{ //unique styles}
#dash3{ //unique styles}
```

Comment: "#DashboardPoolAvailable" must be ".DashboardPoolAvailable"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this starts attribute selector . [see guide](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp)

```
li[id^='DashboardPoolAvailable_']{
display: inline-block; width: 924px; margin: 0px 13px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `E[id^=DashboardPoolAvailable_]` to match your id's

Element E whose attribute `id` starts with the value `DashboardPoolAvailable_`.